# Jenkins build failed : Could not found load main class

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to build on Jenkins. I am getting exception.

> ```
> Established TCP socket on 53837
> [server] $ "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79/bin/java" –Xmx512m –XX:MaxPermSize=128m -cp
> ```
>
> C:\Users\anuj.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven32-agent-1.12-alpha-1.jar;D:\unicmoer\software\apache-maven-3.2.3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.1.jar;D:\unicmoer\software\apache-maven-3.2.3/conf/logging
>   jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven32Main
>   D:\unicmoer\software\apache-maven-3.2.3
>   D:\jenkins\apache-tomcat-7.0.54\webapps\jenkins\WEB-INF\lib\remoting-3.10.jar
>   C:\Users\anuj.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven32-interceptor-1.12-alpha-1.jar
>   C:\Users\anuj.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven3-interceptor-commons-1.12-alpha-1.jar
>   53837
>       Error: Could not find or load main class –Xmx512m
>       ERROR: Failed to launch Maven. Exit code = 1
>       Notifying upstream projects of job completion
>       Finished: FAILURE

Comment: Can you check that the dash in front of `Xmx512m` is a normal dash and not an unicode emdash. In your question it looks like an unicode emdash which is something different than a simple `-`.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved. Problem in –Xmx512m –XX:MaxPermSize=128m

Here, it should be minus(-) sign instead of hyphen.